# Grails: Redirecting actions

Tags: grails

I have a relatively small app. I have 2 actions in my controller, action1 and action2. What I want is that, if my app is accessed in US, the controller will call action1, and if it is accessed in UK, action2 is called. How can I do this? Can someone show me how to do it in URLMappings or in the controller? Or is their another way to do this?

Thank you.

A simple example for a newbie like me would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is to create a filter that will redirect to the appropriate controller depending on the current locale.

More info on [Filters](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html).

**Edit:**

Do something like this:

```
class LocaleFilters {
    def filters = {
        checkLocale(controller: '*', action: '*') {
            before = {
                if (org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request) == Locale.US ) {
                    redirect(action: 'action1')
                    return false
                } else {
                    redirect(action: 'action2')
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering my question. But can you please provide atleast a simple example or a code snippet perhaps, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try this.