# Redirecting using UrlMappings

Tags: grails

How can I do redirect to certain controllers depending on the country my app is accessed? for example, if my app is accesed in china, a certain controller will be redirected. As much as possible, I want to do this on the UrlMappings.groovy for some underlying reasons. A simple code snipped would greatly help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'm not really experienced in Grails, but probably you should check user locale in a controller and then make it call the one you need.

Answer (score 2):

It can be easily done through filters or interceptors. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977417/grails-redirecting-actions) post, this is the best example I see here satisfying the demand. In general, UrlMapping is for RESTful service. In your case if you need 2 different controllers for different Locale, you would end up with 2 URIs which may not be suitable.